# How to add a click event to a button in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a very simple chrome extension that open multiple tabs of LinkedIn searching different keywords that I type in.

Since this is my first extension, most of my codes are based on [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh), which is very similar to my idea.

The problem is when I click my "search" button, nothing happens. I just started coding for a week so I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Besides knowing what is wrong with the codes, is a background script necessary in this case?

Thanks!

Here are my codes:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Search Assistant",
"description": "This extension makes LinkedIn Search easy.",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "js": ["myscript.js"]
}
],
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
"newtab": "newtab.html"
},

"background": {
"scripts": ["bg.js"]
}


}
```

**Popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
body{
font family: Helvetica, Arial, sans;
font-size: 12px;
}
#instruction{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#searcharea{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#search{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#companies{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
<style type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="instruction">Companies you want to search for:</div>
<div id="searcharea"><textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="companies" wrap="soft" tabindex="1"></textarea></div>

<div id="search">
<button id="btn1" tabindex="2">Search</button>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', loadSites);
    document.getElementById('companies').focus();
});

function loadSites(e){
    var companies = document.getElementById('companies').value.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<companies.length; i++){
        thecompany = companies[i].trim();
        thesearchurl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/c?type=companies&keywords=' + thecompany;
        chrome.extension.create({url: thesearchurl, selected:false})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 slight errors right now. Firstly you should use script-tag instead of style to include javascript files. Second: it is better to load javascript after your page is ready. To fix these follow steps below

1. Remove line `<style type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></style>`
2. Add this `<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>` to a line right before `</body>`.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing out. However the button is still not responding.

Comment: @adrienk So you did both of those steps?

Comment: Yes I did. Still the same.

Comment: Do you see any error messages at browser's console? @adrienk Edit: if yes, post them here

Comment: popup.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.create is not a function

Comment: Oh it's solved! I changed it to chrome.tabs.create! Thanks so much!